# Div full height and width dynamic

Tags: jquery, css, height, viewport

Right now I try to make a div with a background image in it that fills the whole viewport on pageload and pushes all the other page-content down if needed, so that you just see this div with the image when you load the page - what's the best way to get this working?

Comment: What are your efforts till now?

Comment: Please provide any screen short or jsfiddle url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/z4zhk/)

This should do it:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}
#imgDiv{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(myImage.png);
}
```

You need to set the height of the `div` to 100%, but this needs to be relative to 'something' which is why you also set `height:100%` for the `html` and `body` elements. As long as the `div` with the image appears first in your HTML, it will work as anticipated.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This is what actually solved my problem: 

`div {
  background-image: url(images/bgindex.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
  height:110%;}`